# Finding closest value by ID with unequal lengths

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame and a vector of unequal lengths. They do not share an id.

```
df <- data.frame( 
  id       = factor(rep(1:24, each = 10)),
  x        = runif(20)*100
                )

a <- sort(runif(100*100))
```

Now, I would really like run over each row of the data frame and **find the location in the vector (a)** of the closest corresponding value for each id.

For a single value, this is just.

```
which.min(abs(df[1, 2] - a))
```

So, if I did it "manually" it would be:

```
a.location <- c(
    which.min(abs(df[1, 2] - a)) 
    which.min(abs(df[2, 2] - a)),
    ...., 
    which.min(abs(df[24, 2] - a)) 
)
```

But I simply can't wrap my head around how I can do this in a function, when I can't merge the data frame and the vector. I've looked at `mapply`, but that doesn't go well with unequal lengths and also `rowwise` from `dplyr`, but haven't had much luck with that either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use rolling join from `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), x)
df1 <- data.table(x=a, id1=1:length(a))
setkey(df1, x)
df1[df, roll="nearest"]
```

`id1` column will give you the desired result.

Comment: Is there another way than data.table? I haven't used it before, and it's kinda messing with the rest of my script suddenly having "data.tables" where I before had data frames.

Comment: There must be many other ways. But likely to be much slower than the data.table approach.